# How to analyze reading time data for regions with different lengths?

Tags: normalization

I'm planing an eye-tracking during reading experiment where I am comparing the effects of two words with significantly different lengths. The sentences I want to compare have basically the following form:

- Name **word** more words, *even* more words.
- Name **long word** more words, *even* more words.
- Name **word** more words, *several* more words.
- Name **long word** more words, *several* more words.

The experiment has two factors (in bold and in italics). The aim is to find out whether:

- **word** + *even* = **long word** + *even*
- **word** + *several* = **long word** + *several*
- **word** + *even* = **word** + *several*

Obviously, **long word** is going to be read for a longer time than **word** and probably fixated more often as well. How can I correct for this? I'm not interested in effects caused word length differences, but effects of word meaning. I could expand the interest area from **word**/**long word** to include "more words" but I fear this will not solve the underlying problem and the effects caused by length will persist.

Unfortunately, I can't add more material to the shorter word because this is a linguistic experiment and the added words could introduce too much noise.
Is there any way in which I can compare the two? How can I account for the difference in length if the length is tied to one of the factors?